# If I want certain workflow governance for different users, do I have to incorporate that in my data model?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, data-modeling

I'm new to coding and am running into an issue that conceptually has my brain in a pretzel. I'm going to try my best to explain it and will link to my github as well, but here it is.. The music app I'm building will have three different user "classifications" or ("Class" in my code):

1. Artists
2. Venue owners
3. Fans

The intention is that when a user signs up they will select a persona (similar to [Bandcamp](https://bandcamp.com/)), which then determines their functionality.

Here's the workflow:

- Everyone is a "user"
- Users either
  a) registers their venue, or
  b) registers their band, or
  c) signs up as a fan

Then, venues can create "events" for bands to play but bands cannot create events. Users can browse both venues and bands to see which events they've hosted/played. Fans can attend events.

I can figure out the controls with authorization but I want to make sure I'm setting up my data model correctly -- and this is where I get confused.

Using my artist model as an example, if an artist is *also* a user, how do I incorporate the user into my artist model? Would adding a "user_id" schema below create a circular reference?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const artistSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Artist must have a name']
  },
  genre: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Contact email required']
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Hometown (so you can be paired with local venues)']
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Artist', artistSchema);
```

Here's a link to my [github](https://github.com/chaseschlachter/musicmaker/tree/main/models) if you need more context on the four models. Thank you!!

Comment: My suggestion, go object oriented. Create a class for each object, then `extend` the artist with the user class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends

Comment: Thanks for sharing - would this sit within a db model? Then I could just extend every variable into "users"?

Comment: Not sure how your data model is set up, are you using a relational db? Sql or nosql?

Comment: MongoDB so it's noSQL. Looking more into "extending" and it seems to be the answer. I'll have to familiarize myself more before actually writing the code but marking @riuCosta's answer correct. Thanks all for the help!